# Get uri props from a data file in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-props

Hi everyone I'm currently working on an app and I have to get the photo_path of a picture in order to show this picture on screen. I tried to access it by creating a `const film = this.props.film` but I got an error like this :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'film.photo_path").

The weird part is that I could access it and I can show it, in an other component but not I the one that i want. And I call it the same way..

Here is the code.

**filmData.js**

```
export default data = [
   {
      id:1,
      name:"Irma",
      photo_path:"http://fr.web.img5.acsta.net/r_1920_1080/medias/nmedia/18/62/85/01/18821912.jpg",
      specialite: "jeu de carte",
      description:"Madame Irma est un personnage de fiction souvent dépeint sous les traits d'une diseuse de bonne aventure"
   },
   {
      id:2,
      name:"Baba",
      photo_path:"http://fr.web.img5.acsta.net/r_1920_1080/medias/nmedia/18/62/85/01/18821912.jpg",
      specialite: "jeu de carte",
      description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

   }
]
```

**FilmDetail.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, ScrollView, Button, Text, FlatList, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

    import MyButton from './MyButton';
    import films from '../Helpers/FilmData';
    import FilmItem2 from './FilmItem2';

    class FilmDetail extends React.Component {
      _displayDetailForFilm = (idFilm) => {
        console.log("Display film with id " + idFilm);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("FilmDetail", { idFilm: idFilm });
      }

      render() {

      const film = this.props.film;

        return (
          <View style={styles.view_container}>
            <ScrollView>
              <View style={styles.photo}>
                <ImageBackground source={{uri: film.photo_path}} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                  <View style={styles.photo_content}>
                    <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)']} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, height: 80 }} />
                    <Text style={styles.nom}>Irma</Text>
                  </View>

                </ImageBackground>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.specialite}>Médium pure</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description}>Mon don me permet de capter des messages précis au travers de mes flashs. Élevée par ma grand-mère avec qui j’ai exercé la voyance au quotidien pendant de nombreuses années. Je peux vous guider sur les points qui vous préoccupent et ressentir l’influence des gens qui vous entourent.</Text>
              <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                <MyButton style={{}} text={"Voyance privée\nouvert 24h/24\n01 44 01 77 01"} icone='icone-transfert' onPress={() => { alert("Voyance privée"); }}/>
                <MyButton text={"Voyance sans CB\nouvert 24h/24\n32 32"} icone='icone-sonnerie' onPress={() => { alert("Voyance sans CB"); }}/>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.titre}>Nos Professionnels{"\n"}de la Voyance</Text>
              <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
              horizontal
              data={films}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => <FilmItem2 film={item} displayDetailForFilm={this._displayDetailForFilm} />} />
              <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginBottom: 35 }}>
                <MyButton text={"Je consulte"} icone='icone-sonnerie' onPress={() => { alert("Je consulte"); }}/>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

export default VoyanteProfil
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you show all the code of FilmDetail.js?

Comment: Just updated it!

Comment: If you're having film is undefined, that means that you're not passing the props to the component when you use it. If you just want to retrieve data from filmData.js, you don't need to call the props, if you want to use your component like `<FilmDetail />` you need to pass the props like `<FilmDetail film={films[index]}`

Comment: I didn't understand it. So if I want to access the `description` field of my data in order to get the path of the uri I would need to do :  `<ImageBackground source={{uri: filmData[description]}} `?

Comment: And why is it working when I'm calling it in an other component ?

Comment: When I say `films[index]` it(s juste because your film data is an array, not a json.
If you're passing a single film as a prop of FilmDetail, your code should work, if you're not passing any props and you just want to use the filmData array, you need to specify the index, like `filmData[0].photo_path`

Comment: The thing is that I want to show the poster_path when i click on the image, so I'm getting the `id`of the film and then i'm showing the image. So this is why i wanted to use props, in the other component i'm doing the same thing but it's working. I'll edit and post the other component